How to Remove Cloud Cover from Landsat 1 Imagery in Google Earth Engine
I'm going to caveat this post with I'm new to Google Earth Engine (played with web browser code editor) and really new to using Javascript language (but getting better).
I am trying to calculate monthly composited values from Landsat 1 in Google Earth Engine and want to make sure cloudy images are not used for a given region. Based on what I've learned the ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(...)does not work for Landsat 1. It seems that in the image properties table CLOUD_COVER is a variable.Is there a way to screen images in a collection to include only images with <20% cloud cover (for example)?
The final product would be a mosaic for a given period with relatively cloud-free images. Below is some example code using GEE in R. However, I have been successful in making the JavaScript to R language conversion.
library(rgee)
library(sf)
ee_Initialize()

# ROI ---------------------------------------------------------------------
rlist=list(xmin=-81.4,xmax=-81.0,ymin=25.8,ymax=25.95)
ROI <- c(rlist$xmin, rlist$ymin,
         rlist$xmax, rlist$ymin,
         rlist$xmax, rlist$ymax,
         rlist$xmin, rlist$ymax,
         rlist$xmin, rlist$ymin)

ee_ROI <- matrix(ROI, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) |>
  list() |>
  st_polygon() |>
  st_sfc() |>
  st_set_crs(4326) |>
  sf_as_ee()

# Image Collection - Oct 1974 ----------------------------------------------
collection <- ee$ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LM01/C02/T2')$
  filterDate('1974-10-01', '1974-10-31')$
  filter(ee$Filter$lt("CLOUD_COVER",20))

## composite and clip ------------------------------------------------------
composite <- collection$mean()
composite_clip=composite$clip(ee_ROI)

## display image -----------------------------------------------------------
Map$setCenter(lon = -81.23789, lat = 25.875944)
Map$setZoom(zoom = 12)

Map$addLayer(
  eeObject = composite_clip,
  visParams = list(bands = c("B6", "B4", "B5"),gamma=1.1),
  name = "max value composite"
)

I tried using ee$Filter$gte("CLOUD_COVER",50) to see if the composited image would produce something with lots of skewed values but it was virtually the same image produced by the above code.
Also is collection$mean() a suitable way to composite or mosaic an ImageCollection for a given period?

UPDATE
copied from comment below as recommended
I believe I may have found the answer. I was on the right track but with the thresholds and period I was using I didn't see a significant change in the image. I used filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER_LAND','less_than',1) and verified by exporting the metadata as a table ee_table_to_drive(...) in rgee.
Also, I might have confused mosaic for composite in my initial comment. From my understanding (and I'll admit it limited)

Mosaic is when you knit together images which could include a way to blend the overlap. For instance in R function raster::mosaic(...) , you have to specify a function to compute cell values where layers overlap.
Composite is when you have a stack of layers and would like to build a single image. Like mosaicing but different ... but some of the same methods could be applied, which caused my confusion.


I believe I may have found the answer. I was on the right track but with the thresholds and period I was using I didn't see a significant change in the image. I used filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER_LAND','less_than',1) and verified by exporting the metadata as a table ee_table_to_drive(...) in rgee.

Embed your 'ah ha!' above as I was noodling through usgs earthdata and finding...nothing. Or better put as answer with why you think it worked and accept.
